# How to check files in jUnit?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I need to cover some tests with JUnit. My method returns java.io.File. What are the attributes I need to check?

- check file size?
- check file name?
- check ...?

How do you write JUnit tests for methods, that operate with files? Is there any frameworks?

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to give a bit more than that to allow us to help you. What exactly do you want to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Method returns java.io.File. What is the best way to check it?

There is no "best way".  It completely depends on what the file is supposed to contain, and what you NEED TO test.

In different situations I might test that:

- the `File` argument is non-null,
- the filepath encoded by the `File` has a given value,
- the corresponding file exists,
- the corresponding file has given length or line count,
- the corresponding file contains a given string (or strings) or pattern (patterns),
- the file contents exactly matches a file of expected output,
- the file contents parses to the same data structure as another file, or
- the file contents parses to some data structure that some other properties.

Comment: Its more than enough. Thanks!

Comment: Method returns XML configuration file.

Comment: It still depends on the context.  Like how the file is generated, and what about it you think needs to be unit tested.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create some temporary files to run tests on then you should try the JUnit Rules with `TemporaryFolder`.

[Here](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/) is an example.

That is a way to prepare your tests with necessary files.

But it all comes down to what you actually want to do and your question is not really giving many clues...

Answer (score 1):

Every test must be based on requirement. For example it can be claimed that method returns name of non-existing file that can be safely created - unit test must check that really no such file:

```
assertTrue(!file.isDirectory() && !file.canRead())
```

When requirements tell you that File returned is file with some properties, you have to check exactly claimed properties. For example per requirements at position 3 you have discover symbol '@'. So your test should check:

1. File really exists, can be read
2. Poistion 3 really contains expected symbol